# Alarm when SQS Queue is not Empty After Certain Time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sqs

#### Use Case

We have 1 sqs that is being consumed by a lambda and we would like to know if all messages in the sqs have been consumed or not after a certain timestamp.

For example, Some other system will start sending messages to the SQS start from 6AM and it will take 4 hours for the lambda to process them all. We would like to know at 10AM, have all messages in the queue been consumed or not.
And we only need to detect the depth of the sqs once every day.

#### Questions.

Is there a easy way to setup the alarm in cloudwatch to achieve our use case?

<s>There are many potential solutions such as use cloudwatch rule to trigger a lambda and detect the size of queue and send metric. We can alarm on the metric, but this seems to be heavy lifting</s>

Comment: Why is alarming on sustained queue depth heavy lifting?

Comment: @jarmod hey! Alarming on the the queue depth is not heavy lifting.
but our use case, is to only alarm after certain time. Because we expect the queue to have some messages for a period of time but not after certain time.

Comment: So, you have a (scheduled?) Lambda consuming the queue and you aren’t able to simply have the queue trigger Lambda whenever messages arrive, so you have to poll for them?

Comment: What do you mean by "sqs that is being consumed by a lambda"? Does the Amazon SQS queue directly trigger the AWS Lambda function?

Comment: @jarmod maybe i did not express my use case properly. just re-edit my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Continual checking**

You can create an Amazon CloudWatch alarm on the `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` metric for the queue.

For example, if you wish to be notified when the queue has not been empty over the past hour, you can create an alarm when **the Min of `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` > 0 for 60 minutes**. This is saying that the smallest number of messages in the queue for the past hour was above zero.

**Checking at a specific time**

If you want to check the queue length at a particular time, you will need to use **Amazon CloudWatch Events** to trigger an **AWS Lambda function** at a given time.

The Lambda function can call [`get_queue_attributes()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.get_queue_attributes) to retrieve `ApproximateNumberOfMessages`. If this is bigger than desired, the Lambda function could send a message to an **Amazon SNS topic**. Users can subscribe to the topic to receive an email or SMS notification.

Comment: Yes, but we really need is to alarm when the sqs is not empty after a fixed time. E.g 10AM everyday. Maybe I did not express my use case properly, just re-edit it.

Comment: I have added another option for a fixed time.

Comment: yeah. That is kind of heavy lifting. It would be nice if cloudwatch can support this directly. But thanks!

Comment: @HuazheYin none of this is heavy lifting despite such a custom, and unusual, requirement. If you want to know if the queue is empty at 10am on certain days then schedule a Lambda to run at 10am on those days and simply check the queue depth. But what if a message arrives on the empty queue at 10:01am? What should happen then? You should think about event based triggers. When something lands in the SQS it can trigger a Lambda to process the message. If it lands within the timeframe that “the queue should be empty” then alert via SNS.

Comment: yup. I could imagine instead of having a dedicated lambda that used for the emitting metric only. I could just use the same lambda that is consuming the sqs to emit a metric at the beginning of the process.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thx for your answer, even though very likely I wont proceed with the solution. but thx for providing it as an alternative which could be helpful for others. 
I am accepting your answer. 
thanks!